# git: fatal: unknown repository extensions found: worktreeconfig

Tags: git, git-worktree

I did a copy of a git repository from a Darwin host to a Linux host (ubuntu 18.04)

As far as I remember, I did not use worktree in this repository, but I might be wrong.

However, when typing "git status" on the repository "at target" (so Linux host), I get the following error:

```
kalou@majapatoche:~/xmp$ git status
fatal: unknown repository extensions found:
        worktreeconfig
```

So I tried to turn of any worktree related option in git config ... which fails

```
kalou@majapatoche:~/xmp$
m1:xmp kalou$ git config --list | grep orktre
extensions.worktreeconfig=true

m1:xmp kalou$ git config  extensions.worktreeconfig=false
error: invalid key: extensions.worktreeconfig=false
```

Trying to dig a little bit more, I remove any file within the .git directory related to "worktree" ... no success either ;

```
kalou@majapatoche:~/xmp$ find . | grep worktree
./.git/config.worktree
kalou@majapatoche:~/xmp$ rm .git/config.worktree
kalou@majapatoche:~/xmp$ git status
fatal: unknown repository extensions found:
        worktreeconfig
```

I'm using the following git version on Ubuntu 18.04 host:

```
kalou@majapatoche:~/xmp$ git --version
git version 2.17.1
```

Any hint on how to solve this ?

Comment: Try `git config --unset-all extensions.worktreeconfig`. Minor unrelated nit: `find . | grep worktree` -> `find . -iname '*worktree*'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `extensions.worktreeconfig` setting, if present and set to `true`, tells Git versions 2.20 and later that added working trees (from `git worktree add`) may have some per-worktree setting(s) in use.

Since your Git is version 2.17, it does not support this.  You can use:

```
git config --unset-all extensions.worktreeconfig
```

to remove the setting,<sup>1</sup> but any per-worktree settings will be lost—not precisely a large loss since they were being ignored.  This setting should never have gotten *set* though, with Git version 2.17.  Archiving the `.git` repository and moving it to a machine with an older Git version (or sharing the `.git` repository directory via some networked file system) can result in this problem; that's one reason you're supposed to use `git clone` rather than simply packing up and moving the `.git` directory.

Alternatively, you could upgrade your Git version to 2.20 or later.  2.17 is pretty old and stale at this point.

---

<sup>1</sup>Setting it to false requires:

```
git config extensions.worktreeconfig false
```

(no `=` character here), but may not work since `extensions.*` settings are special.